# Laravel 5.4 where clauses if $request->jobTitle !null?

Tags: php, laravel, dynamic, where-clause, clause

I built small search form helps me search in jobsTable from db

jobs Table has jobTitle, jobCompany, jobGovernorate, jobLocation and created_at column

And posted data from search form:

{"jobTitle":"designer","jobCompany":null,"jobGovernorate":null,"jobLocation":null,"postingDate":"ad"}

I mean some input may be null, so how to write dynamic where clause for inputs have value, i want search engine able to search by JobTitle, JobCompany or All inputs if have value.

Hint: fields name and table columns name are same

if there's a way to retrieve jobs from my db like

```
DB::table('jobs')->where($request->all())
```

**Sorry for poor english, I don't know how to explain my question**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to define all search fields.

```
$searchFields = ['jobTitle','jobCompany','jobGovernorate','jobLocation','postingDate'];
$jobQuery = DB::table('jobs');
foreach ($searchFields as $field) {
    if ($request->has($field)) {
        $jobQuery->where($field, $request->input($field));
    }
}
$results = $jobQuery->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to code the query, I mean, what are you looking for? 
something like

```
DB::table('jobs')->where([
['jobTitle',  'like', $request->jobTitle . '%'],
['jobCompany', 'like', $request->jobCompany . '%']])->get();
```